# delete integer from NSArray

Tags: nsmutablearray, integer

I have to delete an instance from an array, but when I delete the instance all instances with the same value are deleted. The code I use works great with other objects, like `Sprites`, but not with integers.

Who can point me in the right direction?

The value of `deleteSpriteNr` is de object to delete, i have also used [levelSpriteNrArray removeObjectAtIndex:deleteSpriteNr] at the end of the for loop, but that generates a crash.

i am puzzled.

The code:

```
int tel3 = 0;

for (NSNumber *spriteNr in levelSpriteNrArray ){
    if ( tel3 == deleteSpriteNr ){
        [spriteNrToRemove addObject:spriteNr];
        //[spriteNr removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES]  // does not works with integer;
    }
    tel3++;
}
[levelSpriteNrArray removeObjectsInArray:spriteNrToRemove];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do so. Hope this will help.

```
int tel3 = 0;

NSMutableIndexSet *indexes = [NSMutableIndexSet new];

for (int i = 0; i < [levelSpriteNrArray count]; i++ ){
    if ( tel3 == deleteSpriteNr ){
        [indexes addIndex:i];
        //[spriteNr removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES]  // does not works with integer;
    }
    tel3++;
}
[levelSpriteNrArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexes];
```